# Controller post returning View but doesn't display the View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a **View.cshtml** file in **ViewController** which has a hyperlink. Upon clicking the link, I call an ajax request to POST to a **GreetingController** action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Welcome(MyModel model)
{
    ActionResult result = null;
    Task<bool> createTask = Helper.Create(model);
    try
    {
        bool success = await createTask;
        if (success)
        {
            result = View();
        }
        else
            result = new HttpNotFoundResult("Specified resource was not found.");
    }
    catch
    {
        result = View("Error");
    }
    return result;
}
```

If the method in the POST is succesful, I set the result to the View property. I have a **Welcome.cshtml** view for this Action and I was expecting it to display that but it doesn't. Instead of returning View, I tried returning a RedirectToAction and created a GET version of the Welcome action, but still it didn't show. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/greeting/welcome",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, err) {
    }
});
```

Also, the return call above was originally "return View()". I've changed it to "return result".

Comment: post your Ajax code also

Comment: check your **return** statement . make it **return result**

Comment: @Dane: Thanks that was a left-over when I was trying out things. Updated it back to result but still no luck. I've also tried to throw an exception to see if the View("Error") would show, but it also doesn't.

Comment: @Frebin Francis: AJAX code posted.

Comment: You not adding the returned view to the DOM. In the success callback - `$('#someElement').append(result);` (but perhaps you really don't want to stay on the same page in which case why are you using ajax?). You also need to change `dataType: 'html';` (your returning html, not json)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but I was thinking that this AJAX call was made on View.cshtml which in turn calls Action Welcome which has its own View. I was expecting for ASP.NET to go to that page, I'm not sure how I would use the result for that. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @g_b, Ajax calls stay on the same page. Just make a normal submit. None of this javascript code is required.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - Thanks for the reply. I need to use AJAX because I needed to access data on client side that would be use by the Welcome Action.

Comment: If your wanting to redirect (which you appear to be doing by either `return View()`, `return View("error")` or `HttpNotFoundResult` then there is no point using ajax, because ajax calls stays on the same page - they do not redirect. In any case your controller code makes no sense. Why are you using  `async`? Then if `Helper.Create(model);` fails you return a `HttpNotFoundResult`? (your posting a model - how can that result in a 404 error?)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Ok, based on what you said, I'll try some things. Maybe you should post your comment as an answer so that way, if what I try works, I can mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @g_b, Can't post an answer because I'm not really sure what your trying to do with this code.